# If today's date has passed the X date, then execute stuff in Ubuntu Bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm creating a bash script license system. I want to make a system called End-Date, this system will check if the Today's date has passed the certain date then I want to run commands. You will understand it better on example.

For Example

```bash
#Lets say today is 30.08.2022
scriptdate=30.08.2022
enddate=29.08.2022
#If the $scriptdate has passed the $enddate then run exit command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the YYYY-mm-dd date format, and then it's a simple string comparision

```sh
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
enddate="2022-08-29"

if [[ "$today" > "$enddate" ]]; then
    exit
fi
```